# new operator with CArray results in an error

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, new-operator

I have the following MFC (C++) code that allocates a pointer to an array without the need to raise exceptions in case of low memory condition. I compile it with Visual Studio 2008.

```
struct MY_ITEM_INFO
{
    CString str;
    int n;

    MY_ITEM_INFO()
    {
        n = 0;
    }
};

CArray<MY_ITEM_INFO>* pArrResItems = new (std::nothrow) CArray<MY_ITEM_INFO>();
if(pArrResItems != NULL)
{
    //Got it!

    //Remove it
    delete pArrResItems;
}
```

Which gives me the following error message on a `new` operator line when I try to compile it:

```
error C2665: 'CObject::operator new' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
could be 'void *CObject::operator new(size_t,void *)'
```

Any idea how to make it to compile?

Comment: You can first check if the default version of `new` can be compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I got it, the `new` line should've been this (or take `new` operator from the global namespace):

```
CArray<MY_ITEM_INFO>* pArrResItems = ::new (std::nothrow) CArray<MY_ITEM_INFO>();
```

Evidently the `new` operator for CObject does not support `nothrow_t`.